# Database array into single user defined variables

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Im trying to setup a dynamic settings database for my CMS

Database is set up with two columns.

```
Name | Value

Template | Exige

InstallFolder | v2
```

Basically I want to pull all the data out and put it into different variables.

for example i'm trying to set my base_folder(installation folder) into a variable.

So say $base_folder = $CoreSettings[1] output which should show (v2)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM core_settings";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbc));

$CoreSettings = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

  // add each row returned into an array
   $CoreSettings[] = $row; 

 }

 $base_folder = $CoreSettings;
  foreach( $CoreSettings as $key => $val)
   { $$key = $val; }

var_dump($base_folder);
```

This then outputs:

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Template" ["value"]=> string(5) "exige" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(13) "InstallFolder" ["value"]=> string(2) "v2" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(16) "MaintainanceMode" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Logo" ["value"]=> string(8) "Logo.png" } [4]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "SiteName" ["value"]=> string(18) "Black Nova Designs" } }
```

I would like to just get the InstallFolder Value.

so

```
$base_folder = V2
```

Sorry if this comes across stupid just really racked my brain about, and code is probably quite messed up due to trying multiple methods.

But in the long run I would like to get every setting out of the database and be able to assign a variable to each setting.

for example

```
$SiteName = $CoreSettings[4];
$maintenance = $CoreSettings[2];
```

Thanks In advanced.
Kyle

Comment: In your foreach loop it's `$val['name']` or "InstallFolder". But I think you want to make 2 functions. 1 for getting the data from 1 id and 1 for getting all data

Comment: Could you show a quick example, sorry just trying to refocus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index you `$CoreSettings` array with the values of the 1st column, then you can access the values by the appropriate key:

```
$CoreSettings = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

   // add each row returned into an array
   $CoreSettings[$row['name']] = $row['value']; 

}

echo $CoreSettings['InstallFolder']; //outputs V2
echo $CoreSettings['Template']; //outputs Exige
```

Comment: Using that doesn't seem to output anything at all.

Comment: @KyleHolmes See edit, i missed the fact you where using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Thank you!! So for future proofing if I want to use anything now all I need to do.

   $base_folder = $CoreSettings['InstallFolder'];

and

   $SiteName = $CoreSettings['SiteName'];

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: @KyleHolmes No problem, gald i could help